# How to pass a value from one javascript function to another in html.erb

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

In **html.erb**, I have 2 functions which establish a session and disconnection session:

```
<script>
    var session = initialize_session()
    disconnect_session(session)

    function initialize_session() {
        session = session_init();
        return session;
    }

    function disconnect_session(session) {
        session_end(session);
    }

</script>
```

But the above code errors out. How to get the value from one JavaScript function and pass it to another in JavaScript? Thank you.

Comment: Do you want some value to used in another page or pass some value from one fucntion to another function

Comment: Pass the session object from initialize_session() to disconnect_session(), so answer to your question from one function to another

Comment: Please check my solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var session = initialize_session()
function initialize_session(){  
   var data = {id:"123456789"};
   return data; 
}
disconnect_session(session)
function disconnect_session(seesion){
  alert('Disconnect the session'+session.id)
}
```

The above is the working example

Comment: You can also pass the object

Comment: Welcome @UmaSenthil